# The error on "Recaptcha" when updating devise to version 2.1.0

Tags: devise, recaptcha, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The devise was completely returning a flash alert when "Recaptcha" caught wrong keywords.

But after I updated devise version from 1.4.7 to 2.1.0, 
it always says,
"undefined method `render_with_scope' for #"

Does anyone have the same problem?
Is this all because of compatibility of devise 2.1.0 with "Recaptcha"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same error

In my registration_controller.rb  i change 
**render_with_scope :new** to **render :new**   that worked for my application.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
## This controller overwrite the create method of the users Registration controller
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."
      #render_with_scope :new    #dld one 
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```